# Routing Issue Within Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I am fairly new to Rails and am using Devise for user authentication in a new demo app. I have got Devise to work, along with the confirmable module and email verification.

I am now trying to build a phone verification on top of this. I updated the User model to have three additional fields: phone_number, phone_verified (boolean) and phone_verification_code. I also updated the Registrations Controller to allow the additional field of phone_number by the User model.

Now, in order to set up a phone verification system, I have created a page /user/:id/verify by adding a verify method in UsersController and updating the routes.rb. When I type in the URL, http://localhost:3000/users/10/verify, I see the view for that page.

However, I am trying to get to the view by creating a button on the /app/views/users/show.html.erb and my code below is getting an error. I am trying to get the correct path helper for the button. Can someone please help.

Here is the error:

Showing /home/ubuntu/work/depot/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `verify_user_path' for #<#:0x007fc3740fe3a0>

**app/views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><%= @user.email %></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                <strong>Phone number: </strong><%= @user.phone_number %><br/>
                                <% if @user.phone_verified == nil %>
                                    <%= button_to [:verify, @user] do %>
                                        Verify Phone <strong><%= @user.phone_number %></strong>
                                    <% end %>
                                <% else %>
                                    <strong>Phone Verified: </strong><%= @user.phone_verified %><br/>
                                <% end%>
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UsersController**

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    begin
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      logger.error "Attempt to access an invalid user: #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Attempt to access an invalid user: #{params[:id]}"
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end
  end

  def verify
  end

  def generate_pin
    @user.phone_verification_code = rand(0000..9999).to_s.rjust(4, "0")
    save
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @user = nil
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params[:user]
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update] 
  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  match "users/:id/verify" => "users#verify", via: [:get]
  get 'store/index'

  resources :products
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'
  root 'store#index', as: 'store'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `as` option in your route:

```
match "users/:id/verify" => "users#verify", via: [:get], as: 'verify_user'
```

Then restart your server. This will tell Rails to create the proper URL helper methods: `verify_user_path` and `verify_user_url`

Comment: Thanks. I also has to change the :get to :post as I was using the button_to method. It worked then.

Answer (score 0):

```
match "users/:id/verify" => "users#verify", as: 'verify_user',  via: [:get]
```

Or better way:

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update] do
  get :verify
end
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I was able to get the first method to work (with :post and not :get), but not the second method. Do I also have to include the :post method in the second option?

Comment: You can simple add method: :get for button_to helper. This will generate form with get method. But, the rule of thumb is a :post method in your routes.